# Jquery- Height of div on load content

Tags: jquery, css

As I leave the 2 divs with the same height of 4 result I took a load?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$( ".buscascript<?php echo "$row[id]"; ?>" ).click(function() {
$( "#fechargame" ).show();
$( "#result4" ).show();
$( "#result5" ).show();
$( "#result4" ).load( "busca.php?game=<?php echo "$row[id]"; ?>" );
var altura = $("#result4").height();
$( "#publicidade1a" ).height(altura);
$( "#publicidade" ).height(altura);
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is not clear, consider reformulating your question

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that, the `load` method is asynchronous so you need to find the height in the load callback

```
    $("#result4").load("busca.php?game=<?php echo "$row[id]"; ?>", function () {
        var altura = $("#result4").height();
        $("#publicidade1a").height(altura);
        $("#publicidade").height(altura);

    });
```